# Is adding the word "solution" necessary when listing the materials used in a synthesis?

Tags: solutions

I am editing a chemistry-related paper and the synthesis procedure described is as follows:

> Then, 10 mL of the intermediate were mixed with 10 mL of 1% (w/v)
>   VCPL and 2 mL of 0.1% (w/v) KPS.

I was wondering if one should add the word "solution" after the name of the ingredients as follows:

> Then, 10 mL of the intermediate were mixed with 15 mL of a 2% (w/v)
>   VCPL solution and 3 mL of a 0.2% (w/v) KPT solution.

I think that indicating a volume and a % (w/v) gives it away that you are referring to a solution containing the active ingredient, but should the word "solution" still be added?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the name of the solvent should be mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the repeated addtion of the word "solution" is not needed.

All you want here is to provide a *measured* quantity (e.g., volume), concentration of your reagent in the solvent, and *inferred* quantity (e.g., mmol).  This may be reported in the following pattern, too:

> "1-Cinnamyl-4-methylbenzene (**4a**): The compound **4a** was synthesized from
>   1-methoxy-4-{[(2 *E*)-3-phenylprop-2-en-1-yl]oxy}benzene **2b** ($\pu{240.9 mg}$,
>   $\pu{1.00 mmol}$) with *p*-tolylmagnesium bromide **3a** ($\pu{1.4 mL}$, $\pu{1.1 M}$ in THF, $\pu{1.5 mmol}$) in the presence of **1b** ($\pu{4.1 mg}$, $\pu{1 mol\%}$) in $\ce{Et2O}$ ($\pu{5 mL}$) at room temperature for $\pu{24 h}$ ($\pu{198.0 mg}$, $\pu{95\%}$ yield, colorless liquid)."

(source: Hashimoto *et al.* in *Molecules* 2019, **24**, 2296 ([doi.org/10.3390/molecules24122296](https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/24/12/2296)), section 3.2; open access publication.)

This pattern is seen for inorganic reagents like $\ce{HCl}$ dissolved in water, yet equally available in methanol, 1,4-dioxane, etc. ([example](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/substance/hydrogenchloridesolution3646764701011?lang=en&region=US)); and organometallic reagents, e.g. [butyllithium](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/substance/nbutyllithiumsolution640610972811?lang=en&region=US), [methylmagnesium bromide](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/substance/methylmagnesiumbromidesolution119247516111?lang=en&region=US).